# optimizing looping in python in list operation

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I am using the following code for the iteration. but if the length is high, then this will become time-consuming.

```
a=[11,12,3,4,5,6,15]
b=[1,3,12,15]
c=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
d=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        if b[j]==a[i]:
            d.append(c[i])
print(d)
```

is there any other optimal way to get this done?

thanks in advance

Comment: Making a `dict` of `b` will help considerably.

Answer (score 3):

Checking if collection contains an object is optimized for sets. You could do:

```
b_set = set(b)
[ci for ai, ci in zip(a, c) if ai in b_set]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `in`:

```py
for i,v in enumerate(a):
    if v in b:
        d.append(c[i])
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
d = [v for i,v in enumerate(c) if a[i] in b]
```